# Boolean algebra simplification

Tags: boolean-algebra

Is this the simplest form of the expression?

Given: $$x'y'z+x'yz'+x'yz$$
My work: 
$$x'y(z'+z)+x'yz'=
x'y+x'yz=
x'y(z)$$

Answer (score 1):

You could use Karnaugh maps. Alternatively, notice that:
\begin{align*}
&x'y'z + x'yz' + x'yz \\
&= x'y'z + x'yz' + (x'yz + x'yz) &\text{Idempotent Law}\\
&= (x'y'z + x'yz) + (x'yz' + x'yz) &\text{Commutativity/Associativity Law}\\
&= x'z(y' + y) + x'y(z' + z) &\text{Distributivity Law}\\
&= x'z(1) + x'y(1) &\text{Inverse Law}\\
&= x'z + x'y &\text{Identity Law}\\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

The simplest form is:
                       x'z+ x'y